# Ad Design: What is this style called?

Tags: style-identification

I've noticed that Soylent uses this unique style for all their product's photoshoots. Curious if anyone knows what this style is called or from where it derives.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the style has a name exactly, but I would describe it as 'isometric photography'. This seems to fit in well with the brands bold geometric patterns and grid based layouts, as described by Brian Biles who was commissioned to design branding and stationary concepts: [Soylent concepts](https://www.brianbilesdesign.com/soylent/). It's quite a minimalist style which does look appealing.

Comment: I'd add some more adjectives: isometric still photography with pastel backgrounds

Comment: The hard shadows and strong directional light source are distinctive. Usually shadows are the enemy of product shots.